# xcode 14.2 Error when Calling Objc Method from C++

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using `xcode 14.2` version. An error occurs while creating an app using `Objective-C` and `c++`.
Calling a `c++` function from `objective-c` is fine. But when I call the `objective-c` function from `c++`, an error occurs.

I changed the extension to '.mm' after seeing an article saying that the '.m' extension should be modified to '.mm' in order to use 'objective-c' and 'c++' together.

**OBJC**

```
///objcSum.h

#ifndef objcSum_h
#define objcSum_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "mycpp.hpp"


@interface TDWObject : NSObject

-(NSInteger)addNum:(NSInteger)lhs second:(NSInteger)rhs;
-(NSInteger)getNum;

@end

int TDWObjcSum(int num1, int num2);

#endif /* objcSum_h */
```

```
///objcSum.mm

#import "objcSum.h"

@implementation TDWObject

-(NSInteger)addNum:(NSInteger)lhs second:(NSInteger)rhs
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

-(NSInteger)getNum
{
    MySum mysum;
    NSInteger num = mysum.ObjcCall(10, 100);
    return num;
}

@end

int TDWObjcSum(int num1, int num2)
{
    TDWObject* tdwObject = [[TDWObject alloc]init];
    int res = [tdwObject addNum:num1 second:num2];
    [tdwObject release];
    return res;
}
```

**C++**

```
//myCpp.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int TDWCppSum(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

class MySum {
public:
    int sum(int lhs, int rhs);
    int ObjcCall(int num1, int num2);
    
};

#endif
```

```
#include "mycpp.hpp"
#include "objcSum.h"


int MySum::sum(int lhs, int rhs){
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int TDWCppSum(int a, int b) {
    MySum mysum;
    return mysum.sum(a, b);
//    return MySum{}.sum(a, b);
}

int MySum::ObjcCall(int num1, int num2)
{
    int res = TDWObjcSum(num1, num2);
    return res;
}
```

**Code that calls the actual function**

```
//AppDelegate.mm

TDWObject* tdwObjct = [[TDWObject alloc]init];
          int res = [tdwObjct getNum];
          [tdwObjct release];
```

But when I build it I get an error.

**Error Message**

```
Showing Recent Messages
CompileC /Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/mycpp.o /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios/Runner/mycpp.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target arm64-apple-ios15.3 -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu++11 -stdlib\=libc++ -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -index-store-path /Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Runner-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/device_info_plus/device_info_plus.framework/Headers -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/path_provider_ios/path_provider_ios.framework/Headers -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/pdfx/pdfx.framework/Headers -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/printing/printing.framework/Headers -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/uni_links/uni_links.framework/Headers -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/device_info_plus -F/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/path_provider_ios -F/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/pdfx -F/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/printing -F/Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/uni_links -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/mycpp.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/mycpp.dia -c /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios/Runner/mycpp.cpp -o /Users/sinjeong-won/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-fiwvkgeptrgkurarntkwsxtdzbqb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/mycpp.o -index-unit-output-path /Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/mycpp.o

In file included from /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios/Runner/mycpp.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios/Runner/objcSum.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:523:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSString, Protocol;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:525:9: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
typedef NSString * NSExceptionName NS_TYPED_EXTENSIBLE_ENUM;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:526:9: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
typedef NSString * NSRunLoopMode NS_TYPED_EXTENSIBLE_ENUM;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:528:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromSelector(SEL aSelector);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:529:44: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT SEL NSSelectorFromString(NSString *aSelectorName);
                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:531:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromClass(Class aClass);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:532:53: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT Class _Nullable NSClassFromString(NSString *aClassName);
                                                    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:534:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromProtocol(Protocol *proto) API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5), ios(2.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:534:50: error: unknown type name 'Protocol'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSStringFromProtocol(Protocol *proto) API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5), ios(2.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                                                 ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:535:19: error: unknown type name 'Protocol'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT Protocol * _Nullable NSProtocolFromString(NSString *namestr) API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5), ios(2.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:535:61: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT Protocol * _Nullable NSProtocolFromString(NSString *namestr) API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.5), ios(2.0), watchos(2.0), tvos(9.0));
                                                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:539:30: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) NS_NO_TAIL_CALL;
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:539:53: error: format argument not an NSString
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) NS_NO_TAIL_CALL;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ^                  ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:94:49: note: expanded from macro 'NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION'
        #define NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(F,A) __attribute__((format(__NSString__, F, A)))
                                                       ^                    ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:540:31: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,0) NS_NO_TAIL_CALL;
                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:540:63: error: format argument not an NSString
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSLogv(NSString *format, va_list args) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,0) NS_NO_TAIL_CALL;
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                ^                  ~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:94:49: note: expanded from macro 'NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION'
        #define NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(F,A) __attribute__((format(__NSString__, F, A)))
                                                       ^                    ~
In file included from /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios/Runner/mycpp.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios/Runner/objcSum.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:9:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSString;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:19:63: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSSetZoneName(NSZone * _Nullable zone, NSString *name)NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("Zone-based memory management is unavailable");
                                                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:20:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSZoneName(NSZone * _Nullable zone) NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("Zone-based memory management is unavailable");
                  ^
In file included from /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios/Runner/mycpp.cpp:9:
In file included from /Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/elfscoreprint_mobile_20230220/ios/Runner/objcSum.h:11:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:10:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSInvocation, NSMethodSignature, NSCoder, NSString, NSEnumerator;
^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Comment: @DonMag I vote to reopen here. While the duplicated question asks what are possible ways to implement the interoperability, this question asks why a specific approach doesn't work as expected. If OP asked me about that in the comment section without editing his question to add another question I would insist him to ask a separate question, because it's going to be hard to both: for OP to express the details of his problems and for me to express answer as a separate comment. Also, [editing a question in order to add new questions is not embraced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you employ C-code as a common interface for Objective-C and C++, it means you have to avoid literally any use of either of the language but the C language part in order to keep the interface compatible with both C++ and Objective-C.

I.e when importing a header to **Objective-C** code, your header should not contain any of:

- C++ classes
- C++ templates
- C++ overloaded operators
- C++ specific keywords
- C++ modules
- Anything else C++ supports but C doesn't
- Any of the above indirectly imported via `#include` or `#import` directive

Likewise, **C++** code should not see any of Objective-C statements via the included headers:

- `@interface` sections (including categories)
- `@implementation` sections of any `@interface`
- Any other Objective-C specific keywords (e.g `@end`, `@property` or `@synthesize`).
- Any of Objective-C specific macros (like `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN` or `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE`)
- Anything else Objective-C supports, but C doesn't
- Any of the above indirectly imported via `#include` or `#import` directive

---

An apparent approach here is to move anything language specific to the corresponding implementation file. E.g. a function with C++ implementation might look something like this:

```c
//
//  MyClass.h
//

#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int TDWCppSum(int lhs, int rhs);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

While the implementation file contains everything else:

```cpp
//
//  MyClass.cpp
//

#include "MyClass.h"
#include "TDWClass.h"

#pragma mark - C++ implementation

class MySum {
public:
    int cppSum(int lhs, int rhs);
    int objcSum(int lhs, int rhs);

};

int MySum::cppSum(int lhs, int rhs){
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int MySum::objcSum(int num1, int num2) {
    return TDWObjcSum(num1, num2);
}

#pragma mark - Public API implementation

int TDWCppSum(int lhs, int rhs) {
    return MySum{}.cppSum(lhs, rhs);
}
```

`TDWClass.h` in this case is the header that contains function declaration that refers to the Objective-C implementation:

```c
//
//  TDWClass.h
//

#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int TDWObjcSum(int lhs, int rhs);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And this is the implementation file for this header:

```objc
//
//  TDWClass.m
//

#import "TDWClass.h"
#import "MyClass.h"

#pragma mark - Objective-C implementation

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TDWClass : NSObject

- (NSInteger)objcSum:(NSInteger)lhs :(NSInteger)rhs;
- (NSInteger)cppSum:(NSInteger)lhs :(NSInteger)rhs;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

@implementation TDWClass

- (NSInteger)objcSum:(NSInteger)lhs :(NSInteger)rhs {
    return lhs + rhs;
}

- (NSInteger)cppSum:(NSInteger)lhs :(NSInteger)rhs; {
    return TDWCppSum((int)lhs, (int)rhs);
}

#pragma mark - Public API implementation

int TDWObjcSum(int lhs, int rhs) {
    return (int)[[TDWClass new] objcSum:lhs :rhs];
}

@end
```

As you can see neither of the headers exposes which language implements it and they are 100% compatible with each other (you implement with any of C, C++ or Objective-C language)

Also be advised that *any header* you refer to from C++ compilation units **and** C/Objective-C compilation units have to be wrapped with `extern "C"` guards in order to avoid linking errors.

Here how `AppDelegate.m` could have the corresponding functions called:

```objc
...
#import "MyClass.h"
#import "TDWClass.h"
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"Cpp sum: %d", TDWCppSum(4, 8));
    NSLog(@"ObjC sum: %d", TDWObjcSum(16, 32));
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thank you It took quite a while but I solved it with your answer.